# Context free grammar for a language

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I have this `context free language`

$L = \{x^{3i} y^j z^k\ |\ i \ge 0 \land k \gt 2j \gt 0\}$

I'm working out a `context free grammar` that would generate that `language`.

I think there should be either `1` or `3 times` `x`s, and `2 times plus 1` more `z` than `y`.

Therefore my solution would be:

$S \rightarrow TVU$
$T \rightarrow x \ |\  xxxU$
$U \rightarrow VzzUzU$
$V \rightarrow y \ |\  yV$

Is that fine?

Edit 1 (based on Baranovskiy comment):

$S \rightarrow TVU$
$T \rightarrow x \ |\  xxxU$
$U \rightarrow VzzUz$
$V \rightarrow y \ |\  yV$

Edit 2 (based on Baranovskiy comment):

$S \rightarrow TyUz^3V$
$T \rightarrow xxxT\ |\ \lambda$ (Since x can be $x^0$)
$U \rightarrow yVzz\ |\ \lambda$
$V \rightarrow zV \ |\ \lambda$

Comment: For now it doesn't work e.g. $S \to XYZ \to xYZ \to xyZ \to xyYzzZz \to xyzzYzzZzz \to xyzzyzzzz$. Are you sure that you want $x^{3^i}y^jz^k$ instead $x^{3i}y^jz^k$?

Comment: @Baranovskiy Sorry it was a typo, I'll fix right away!

Comment: Nope your second version still doesn't work; you have to isolate $z$-s from $y$-s (there is a problem with $U \to VzzUzU$) maybe consider something like $S \to TyUVz^3$, $T \to xxxT | \varepsilon $, $U \to yUzz | \varepsilon$, $V \to Vz | \varepsilon$ this form should guarantee us that $k > 2j > 0$ imo it works.

Comment: z should be twice plus one y's. Thats why I wrote VzzUz

Comment: not at all it should be not less then twice plus one y's moreover $T \to x$ may generate both $x^{3j}$ or $x^{3j + 1}$ while we want only the first ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm making an answer from comment. The important thing in this problem is to guarantee that $k > 2j > 0$ will hold in consecutive iterations and we have obviously start with a word at form $TyUVz^3$ to fulfill the same assumption. Hence solution may be following:

$S \to TyUVz^3$

$T \to xxxT | \varepsilon$

$U \to yUzz | \varepsilon$

$V \to Vz | \varepsilon$

Comment: Does this generate x^6yz^3?

Comment: $S \to TyUVz^3 \to x^3TyUVz^3 \to x^6TyUVz^3 \to x^6 \varepsilon y \varepsilon \varepsilon z^3 = x^6yz^3$

Comment: I see, thank you (+1)

Comment: The variable $U$ and $V$ can be merged into one. $S\to TyUz^3$, $U\to yUzz \mid Uz\mid \varepsilon$.