# Push down automata for context free grammar

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I'm having trouble finding the `PDA` for this language

$L = \{x^{3i} y^j z^k\ |\ i \ge 0 \land k \gt 2j \gt 0\}$

The `free context grammar` is

$$S \rightarrow TyUz^3$$ 
$$T \rightarrow xxxT\ |\ \lambda$$
$$U \rightarrow yVzz\ |\ \lambda$$
$$V \rightarrow zV \ |\ \lambda$$

Here's my try:

- Any multiple of 3 number of `x`s
  $$(q_0, x, z_0) \vdash (q_1, z_0)$$
  $$(q_1, x, z_0) \vdash (q_2, z_0)$$
  $$(q_2, x, z_0) \vdash (q_0, z_0)$$
- Then `y`s, we must store two symbols per each (not necessary a state change)
  $$(q_0, b, z_0) \vdash (q_0, bbz_0)$$
  $$(q_0, b, b) \vdash (q_0, bbb)$$
- Then `z`s.
  $$(q_0, z, b) \vdash (q_3, \lambda)$$
  $$(q_3, z, b) \vdash (q_3, \lambda)$$
  $$(q_3, z, z_0) \vdash (q_f, z_0)$$
  $$(q_f, z, z_0) \vdash (q_f, z_0)$$
  $$(q_f, \lambda, z_0) \vdash (q_f, \lambda)$$

Comment: Your grammar is wrong -- it doesn't generate $x^6yz^3$, for example.

Comment: It may be easier to construct a PDA directly if you rewrite the language description to $(xxx)^*\{y^j(zz)^j\mid j\ge 1\}zz^*$ first.

Comment: The grammar is from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611913/context-free-grammar-for-a-language

Comment: x @ssedano: The answer there has $T\to xxxT$, not $T\to xxxU$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, it was a mistake of mine

Comment: If you reuse state $q_0$ for handling both $x$ and $y$ you might get them in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple method of transforming a CFG into an PDA having a single state and acceptance by empty stack. It is the expand-match method, and is explained on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_Context-free_Languages).

For each production $X\to\alpha$ we expand $(1,\varepsilon,1,X,\alpha)$ and for each terminal symbol $a$ we match $(1,a,1,a,\varepsilon)$. Thus expanding is simulationg the production, but on the stack, and matching means we check whether the symbol produced is actually on the input. One technicality: in this way of writing the stack for the PDA it is assumed its Top is written on the left, so it represents the sentential form derived by the grammar.

This method does not use states. Therefore directly programming your PDA might give both a simpler automaton and better understanding.